# Put a character in between every character of all strings in a cell-array

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have `input-cell = {'ABCD', 'ABD', 'BCD'}`. How can I put the operator `<` into the strings in input-cell?

The expected output should be:

```
 output-cell = {'A<B<C<D', 'A<B<D', 'B<C<D'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert a fixed character (`<`) between the characters of each string in a cell array: you can use [`regexeprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) as follows:

```
input_cell = {'ABCD', 'ABD', 'BCD'};                        %// input cell array
c = '<';                                                    %// character to be inserted
output_cell = regexprep(input_cell, '.(?=.)', ['$0' c]);    %// output cell array
```

Result:

```
output_cell = 
    'A<B<C<D'    'A<B<D'    'B<C<D'
```

Comment: Damn, I was working on a regex solution as well, but you ware faster! This is the way to go.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
inputcell = {'ABCD', 'ABD', 'BCD'}; %// Initial cell
outputcell = cell(size(inputcell)); %// Initialise output
for ii = 1:numel(inputcell)
    tmp = inputcell{ii}; %// grab the iith cell
    tmp2=[]; %// Initialise empty collector
    tmp2(1:2:numel(tmp)*2)=tmp; %// Put characters on odd indices
    tmp2(tmp2==0)='<'; %// Fill the even indices with <
    outputcell{ii} = tmp2(1:end-1); %// Store the new string
    clear tmp2 %// Clear the temporary string
end
outputcell
outputcell = 
    'A<B<C<D'    'A<B<D'    'B<C<D'
```

This uses the fact that each entry into your `inputcell` is an `1xN` character array which you can access using indices. Just append `<` after each letter and store the new string`. Thanks to @Daniel for the removal of the inner loop.

Comment: Basically the right way to go. You can remove the inner loop using `tmp2=[];tmp2(1:2:numel(tmp)*2)=tmp;tmp2(tmp2==0)='<'`, which is probably faster for long strings.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel added that to the loop. Any way to eliminate the outer loop as well with e.g. `cellfun` or so?

Comment: Might be possible, but `cellfun` won't speed up the code, thus I don't see any advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it. You can append the number of `<` that you need to the end of each cell with

```
t = strcat(input_cell{n}, repmat('<', 1, length(input_cell{n})-1));
```

and then you can simply rearrange the characters in each cell to place the `<` in the correct positions

```
output_cell{n}(1:2:length(t)) = t(1:ceil(length(t)/2));
output_cell{n}(2:2:length(t)) = t(1+ceil(length(t)/2):length(t));
```

Putting this altogether gives

```
input_cell = {'ABCD', 'ABD', 'BCD'};
output_cell = cell(size(input_cell));

for n = 1:length(output_cell)
    t = strcat(input_cell{n}, repmat('<', 1, length(input_cell{n})-1));
    output_cell{n}(1:2:length(t)) = t(1:ceil(length(t)/2));
    output_cell{n}(2:2:length(t)) = t(1+ceil(length(t)/2):length(t));
end
```

which produces

```
>> output_cell
output_cell = 

    'A<B<C<D'    'A<B<D'    'B<C<D'
```